# For loop using the length of a function call with a passed argument, what property is providing the value for length?

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, object

I'm going through Chapter 4 of Eloquent JavaScript in case anyone wants to see exactly what's going on. https://eloquentjavascript.net/04_data.html.

I'm trying to understand where this For loop grabs its length value from.

```
for (let event of journalEvents(JOURNAL)) {
  console.log(event + ":", phi(tableFor(event, JOURNAL)));
```

As I understand from earlier in the chapter, this For loop could also be written as:

```
for (let i = 0; i < journalEvents(JOURNAL).length; i++) {
  let event = journalEvents(JOURNAL)[i];
  console.log(event + ":", phi(tableFor(event, JOURNAL))); 
}
```

This means the length can be found somewhere in the function journalEvents() when passed the arguement JOURNAL.

```
function journalEvents(journal) {
  let events = [];
  for (let entry of journal) {
    for (let event of entry.events) {
      if (!events.includes(event)) {
        events.push(event);
      }
    }
  }
  return events;
}
```

At this point, I'm a little lost. I am guessing I need to determine the value of journalEvents(JOURNAL). Is it going to be the return value of the function?
The return value is the array events[]. Does this mean the length value is the length of events[]?

Comment: What's about `journalEvents(JOURNAL).length`?

Comment: "*When a for loop looks like this, with the word of after a variable definition, it will loop over the elements of the value given after of. This works not only for arrays but also for strings and some other data structures. We’ll discuss how it works in [Chapter 6](https://eloquentjavascript.net/06_object.html#h_z2tOOXM8qO).*" And no, it does not just access the `.length`.

Comment: This [for...of](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) could help.

Answer (score 0):

**The answer is yes**, the length value is that of the `events` array. However, length is not really a direct factor here. Arrays are iterables, so you can iterate through them with `for...of` loops. You can easily test this by changing the function `journalEvents` so that it returns a number, and see what happens :)

Answer (score 0):

The function `journalEvents(journal)` returns an array, which is added to inside the function. Basically this is the same as putting the array that the function returns wherever you put `journalEvents(journal)`:

```
for (let event of [something]) {
  console.log(event + ":", phi(tableFor(event, JOURNAL)));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Notice that the `for…of` loop only would call `journalEvents(JOURNAL)` once, and then iterates of the result value. If you want to rewrite it to a "normal" loop, you should introduce a temporary variable for that:

```
const events = journalEvents(JOURNAL);
for (let i = 0; i < events.length; i++) {
  const event = events[i];
  console.log(event + ":", phi(tableFor(event, JOURNAL))); 
}
```

> Does this mean the length value is the length of events[]?

Yes.